# Deleted matrix block means deleted data?

Tags: matrix, database, performance, optimization

If I delete the Matrix block content (while editing an entry) does the associated is deleted as well or only the block but its data still remains in db?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any content or relationships that belong to the Matrix block will also be deleted, *when you save the entry*. If there were any relationships, the target elements won’t be deleted, though.

Comment: To be clear – OP specifically mentions editing an entry – if you're deleting a Matrix block while editing an entry, the Matrix block (and it's data/content) won't _actually_ be deleted until you (re)save the entry.

Comment: @MatsMikkelRummelhoff Hm yeah ok, just clarified the answer.